# Windows XP / active perl 5.12.3 / XML::LibXSLT / unable to install

Tags: xml, perl, activeperl

I am trying to install XML::LibXSLT package on my dev machine but its not working. First of all PPM GUI doesn't even show this package and when i try to install it using cpan i get following error:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\sourabh.shankar>cpan
Set up gcc environment - 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.9456)
Enter 'h' for help.


cpan> install XML::LibXSLT
Going to read 'C:\Perl\cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 20 Oct 2011 10:29:10 GMT
Running install for module 'XML::LibXSLT'
Running make for S/SH/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXSLT-1.73.tar.gz
Checksum for C:\Perl\cpan\sources\authors\id\S\SH\SHLOMIF\XML-LibXSLT-1.73.tar.g
z ok
Scanning cache C:\Perl/cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE

XML-LibXSLT-1.73/
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/README
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/LibXSLT.pm
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/LibXSLT.xs
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/perl-libxml-mm.c
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/Makefile.PL
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/benchmark/
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/benchmark/benchmark.pl
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/benchmark/Driver/
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/benchmark/Driver/LibXSLT.pm
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/benchmark/Driver/BaseClass.pm
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/benchmark/Driver/Sablotron.pm
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/example/
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/example/nonfatal.xsl
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/example/bad3.xsl
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/example/1.xsl
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/example/fatal.xsl
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/example/bad2.xsl
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/example/2.xsl
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/example/bad1.xsl
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/example/2.xml
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/example/1.xml
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/t/
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/t/01basic.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/t/09exslt.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/t/15misc.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/t/12import.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/t/03input.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/t/13error.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/t/07blankdoc.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/t/06entities.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/t/11utf8.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/t/02dromeds.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/t/05quick.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/t/14security.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/t/04params.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/t/06output.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/t/10functions.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/t/08literal.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/MANIFEST
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/typemap
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/testcases/
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/testcases/default.conf
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/ppport.h
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/perl-libxml-mm.h
XML-LibXSLT-1.73/Changes

  CPAN.pm: Going to build S/SH/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXSLT-1.73.tar.gz

Set up gcc environment - 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
looking for -llibxslt... yes
looking for -llibexslt... yes
running pkg-config libexslt... failed
using fallback values for LIBS and INC
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -llibxslt
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -llibxml2
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lzlib
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -llibexslt
Writing Makefile for XML::LibXSLT
cp LibXSLT.pm blib\lib\XML\LibXSLT.pm
C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe C:\Perl\lib\ExtUtils\xsubpp  -typemap C:\Perl\lib\ExtUtils\
typemap -typemap typemap  LibXSLT.xs > LibXSLT.xsc && C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe -MExt
Utils::Command -e "mv" -- LibXSLT.xsc LibXSLT.c
C:/Perl/site/bin/gcc.exe -c     -DNDEBUG -DWIN32 -D_CONSOLE -DNO_STRICT -DHAVE_D
ES_FCRYPT -DUSE_SITECUSTOMIZE -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_
PERLIO -D_USE_32BIT_TIME_T -DPERL_MSVCRT_READFIX -DHASATTRIBUTE -fno-strict-alia
sing -mms-bitfields -O2           -DVERSION=\"1.73\"    -DXS_VERSION=\"1.73\"  "
-IC:\Perl\lib\CORE"  -DHAVE_BLANK -DHAVE_BLANK -DHAVE_EXSLT LibXSLT.c
LibXSLT.xs:12:32: libxslt/xsltconfig.h: No such file or directory
LibXSLT.xs:13:26: libxslt/xslt.h: No such file or directory
LibXSLT.xs:14:35: libxslt/xsltInternals.h: No such file or directory
LibXSLT.xs:15:31: libxslt/transform.h: No such file or directory
LibXSLT.xs:16:31: libxslt/xsltutils.h: No such file or directory
LibXSLT.xs:17:29: libxslt/imports.h: No such file or directory
LibXSLT.xs:18:32: libxslt/extensions.h: No such file or directory
LibXSLT.xs:19:30: libxslt/security.h: No such file or directory
LibXSLT.xs:21:28: libexslt/exslt.h: No such file or directory
LibXSLT.xs:22:34: libexslt/exsltconfig.h: No such file or directory
LibXSLT.xs:24:30: libxml/xmlmemory.h: No such file or directory
LibXSLT.xs:25:29: libxml/HTMLtree.h: No such file or directory
LibXSLT.xs:26:26: libxml/xmlIO.h: No such file or directory
LibXSLT.xs:27:25: libxml/tree.h: No such file or directory
LibXSLT.xs:28:27: libxml/parser.h: No such file or directory
LibXSLT.xs:29:36: libxml/parserInternals.h: No such file or directory
LibXSLT.xs:30:35: libxml/xpathInternals.h: No such file or directory
In file included from LibXSLT.xs:34:
perl-libxml-mm.h:55: error: syntax error before "xmlNodePtr"
perl-libxml-mm.h:55: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
perl-libxml-mm.h:56: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
perl-libxml-mm.h:58: error: syntax error before '}' token
perl-libxml-mm.h:61: error: syntax error before "xmlNodePtr"
perl-libxml-mm.h:61: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
perl-libxml-mm.h:62: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
perl-libxml-mm.h:66: error: syntax error before '}' token
perl-libxml-mm.h:119: error: syntax error before "node"
perl-libxml-mm.h:122: error: syntax error before "document"
perl-libxml-mm.h:131: error: syntax error before "node"
perl-libxml-mm.h:165: error: syntax error before "x_PmmSvNodeExt"
perl-libxml-mm.h:165: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
perl-libxml-mm.h:183: error: syntax error before "x_PmmSvOwner"
perl-libxml-mm.h:183: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
perl-libxml-mm.h:192: error: syntax error before "node"
perl-libxml-mm.h:198: error: syntax error before "ctxt"
perl-libxml-mm.h:201: error: syntax error before "x_PmmSvContext"
perl-libxml-mm.h:201: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
perl-libxml-mm.h:216: error: syntax error before "x_PmmCloneNode"
perl-libxml-mm.h:216: error: syntax error before "node"
perl-libxml-mm.h:216: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
perl-libxml-mm.h:233: error: syntax error before "node"
perl-libxml-mm.h:245: error: syntax error before "elem"
perl-libxml-mm.h:247: error: syntax error before '*' token
perl-libxml-mm.h:248: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
perl-libxml-mm.h:251: error: syntax error before '*' token
perl-libxml-mm.h:269: error: syntax error before '*' token
perl-libxml-mm.h:284: error: syntax error before '*' token
perl-libxml-mm.h:285: error: syntax error before '*' token
perl-libxml-mm.h:285: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
perl-libxml-mm.h:288: error: syntax error before '*' token
perl-libxml-mm.h:290: error: syntax error before '*' token
perl-libxml-mm.h:291: error: syntax error before "xmlNodePtr"
perl-libxml-mm.h:291: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
LibXSLT.xs: In function `LibXSLT_init_error_ctx':
LibXSLT.xs:167: error: `xmlGenericErrorFunc' undeclared (first use in this funct
ion)
LibXSLT.xs:167: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
LibXSLT.xs:167: error: for each function it appears in.)
LibXSLT.xs:167: error: syntax error before "LibXSLT_error_handler_ctx"
LibXSLT.xs:168: error: syntax error before "LibXSLT_error_handler_ctx"
LibXSLT.xs: At top level:
LibXSLT.xs:226: error: syntax error before "ctxt"
LibXSLT.xs: In function `LibXSLT__function':
LibXSLT.xs:227: error: `xmlXPathObjectPtr' undeclared (first use in this functio
n)
LibXSLT.xs:227: error: syntax error before "obj"
LibXSLT.xs:228: error: `xmlNodeSetPtr' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:239: error: `xmlNodePtr' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:239: error: syntax error before "tmp_node"
LibXSLT.xs:240: error: `xmlDocPtr' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:241: error: `xsltTransformContextPtr' undeclared (first use in this f
unction)
LibXSLT.xs:248: error: `perl_function' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:251: error: `nargs' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:252: error: `obj' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:252: error: syntax error before "valuePop"
LibXSLT.xs:254: error: `XPATH_NODESET' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:255: error: `XPATH_XSLT_TREE' undeclared (first use in this function)

LibXSLT.xs:256: error: `nodelist' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:263: error: syntax error before "tnode"
LibXSLT.xs:267: error: `tnode' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:268: error: `XML_NAMESPACE_DECL' undeclared (first use in this functi
on)
LibXSLT.xs:271: error: `xmlNsPtr' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:271: error: syntax error before "tnode"
LibXSLT.xs:277: error: syntax error before "tnode_cpy"
LibXSLT.xs:278: error: `tnode_cpy' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:281: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
LibXSLT.xs:281: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
LibXSLT.xs:291: error: `XPATH_BOOLEAN' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:295: error: `XPATH_NUMBER' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:299: error: `XPATH_STRING' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:329: error: `ret' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:329: error: syntax error before "xmlXPathNewCString"
LibXSLT.xs:339: error: `tctxt' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:346: error: `tmp_node1' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:346: error: syntax error before "x_PmmSvNodeExt"
LibXSLT.xs:348: error: `container' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:359: error: `tmp_node' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:362: error: `tmp_node2' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:362: error: `xmlChar' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:362: error: syntax error before ')' token
LibXSLT.xs:363: error: syntax error before "container"
LibXSLT.xs:373: error: syntax error before "x_PmmSvNodeExt"
LibXSLT.xs:374: error: syntax error before "xmlXPathNewNodeSet"
LibXSLT.xs:393: error: `XML_ELEMENT_NODE' undeclared (first use in this function
)
LibXSLT.xs:395: error: syntax error before ')' token
LibXSLT.xs:396: error: syntax error before "container"
LibXSLT.xs:399: error: syntax error before "container"
LibXSLT.xs:409: error: syntax error before "xmlXPathNewBoolean"
LibXSLT.xs:414: error: syntax error before "xmlXPathNewCString"
LibXSLT.xs:419: error: syntax error before "xmlXPathNewFloat"
LibXSLT.xs:423: error: syntax error before "xmlXPathNewCString"
LibXSLT.xs:426: error: `ctxt' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs: At top level:
LibXSLT.xs:439: error: syntax error before "ctxt"
LibXSLT.xs: In function `LibXSLT_generic_function':
LibXSLT.xs:446: error: `ctxt' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:458: error: `nargs' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs: At top level:
LibXSLT.xs:470: error: syntax error before "ctxt"
LibXSLT.xs: In function `LibXSLT_context_function':
LibXSLT.xs:480: error: `xsltTransformContextPtr' undeclared (first use in this f
unction)
LibXSLT.xs:480: error: syntax error before "tctxt"
LibXSLT.xs:482: error: `tctxt' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:490: error: `ctxt' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:504: error: `nargs' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs: At top level:
LibXSLT.xs:508: error: syntax error before "ctxt"
LibXSLT.xs: In function `LibXSLT_context_element':
LibXSLT.xs:517: error: `xmlNodePtr' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:517: error: syntax error before "result"
LibXSLT.xs:519: error: `ctxt' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:529: error: `inst' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:549: error: `node' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:571: error: `result' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs: At top level:
LibXSLT.xs:766: error: syntax error before "option"
LibXSLT.xs: In function `LibXSLT_security_check':
LibXSLT.xs:784: error: `option' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:785: error: `ctxt' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:787: error: `value' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs: At top level:
LibXSLT.xs:815: error: syntax error before "sec"
LibXSLT.xs: In function `LibXSLT_security_read_file':
LibXSLT.xs:819: error: `XSLT_SECPREF_READ_FILE' undeclared (first use in this fu
nction)
LibXSLT.xs:819: error: `sec' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:819: error: `ctxt' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:819: error: `value' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs: At top level:
LibXSLT.xs:823: error: syntax error before "sec"
LibXSLT.xs: In function `LibXSLT_security_write_file':
LibXSLT.xs:827: error: `XSLT_SECPREF_WRITE_FILE' undeclared (first use in this f
unction)
LibXSLT.xs:827: error: `sec' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:827: error: `ctxt' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:827: error: `value' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs: At top level:
LibXSLT.xs:831: error: syntax error before "sec"
LibXSLT.xs: In function `LibXSLT_security_create_dir':
LibXSLT.xs:835: error: `XSLT_SECPREF_CREATE_DIRECTORY' undeclared (first use in
this function)
LibXSLT.xs:835: error: `sec' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:835: error: `ctxt' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:835: error: `value' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs: At top level:
LibXSLT.xs:839: error: syntax error before "sec"
LibXSLT.xs: In function `LibXSLT_security_read_net':
LibXSLT.xs:843: error: `XSLT_SECPREF_READ_NETWORK' undeclared (first use in this
 function)
LibXSLT.xs:843: error: `sec' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:843: error: `ctxt' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:843: error: `value' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs: At top level:
LibXSLT.xs:847: error: syntax error before "sec"
LibXSLT.xs: In function `LibXSLT_security_write_net':
LibXSLT.xs:851: error: `XSLT_SECPREF_WRITE_NETWORK' undeclared (first use in thi
s function)
LibXSLT.xs:851: error: `sec' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:851: error: `ctxt' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:851: error: `value' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs: At top level:
LibXSLT.xs:855: error: syntax error before "LibXSLT_init_security_prefs"
LibXSLT.xs:855: error: syntax error before "ctxt"
LibXSLT.xs: In function `LibXSLT_init_security_prefs':
LibXSLT.xs:857: error: `xsltSecurityPrefsPtr' undeclared (first use in this func
tion)
LibXSLT.xs:857: error: syntax error before "sec"
LibXSLT.xs:858: error: `sec' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:860: error: `XSLT_SECPREF_READ_FILE' undeclared (first use in this fu
nction)
LibXSLT.xs:862: error: `XSLT_SECPREF_WRITE_FILE' undeclared (first use in this f
unction)
LibXSLT.xs:864: error: `XSLT_SECPREF_CREATE_DIRECTORY' undeclared (first use in
this function)
LibXSLT.xs:866: error: `XSLT_SECPREF_READ_NETWORK' undeclared (first use in this
 function)
LibXSLT.xs:868: error: `XSLT_SECPREF_WRITE_NETWORK' undeclared (first use in thi
s function)
LibXSLT.xs:871: error: `ctxt' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs: At top level:
LibXSLT.xs:877: error: syntax error before "sec"
LibXSLT.xs: In function `LibXSLT_free_security_prefs':
LibXSLT.xs:880: error: `sec' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs: At top level:
LibXSLT.xs:894: error: syntax error before "ctxt"
LibXSLT.xs: In function `LibXSLT_init_functions':
LibXSLT.xs:903: error: `wrapper' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:917: error: `ctxt' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:918: error: syntax error before "xmlChar"
LibXSLT.xs: At top level:
LibXSLT.xs:926: error: syntax error before "ctxt"
LibXSLT.xs: In function `LibXSLT_init_elements':
LibXSLT.xs:935: error: `wrapper' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:949: error: `ctxt' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:950: error: syntax error before "xmlChar"
LibXSLT.xs: In function `XS_XML__LibXSLT_LIBXSLT_DOTTED_VERSION':
LibXSLT.xs:994: error: `LIBXSLT_DOTTED_VERSION' undeclared (first use in this fu
nction)
LibXSLT.xs: In function `XS_XML__LibXSLT_LIBXSLT_VERSION':
LibXSLT.xs:1002: error: `LIBXSLT_VERSION' undeclared (first use in this function
)
LibXSLT.xs: In function `XS_XML__LibXSLT_LIBXSLT_RUNTIME_VERSION':
LibXSLT.xs:1009: error: `xsltLibxsltVersion' undeclared (first use in this funct
ion)
LibXSLT.xs: In function `XS_XML__LibXSLT_max_depth':
LibXSLT.xs:1030: error: `xsltMaxDepth' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs: In function `XS_XML__LibXSLT_register_function':
LibXSLT.xs:1051: error: syntax error before "xmlChar"
LibXSLT.xs: In function `XS_XML__LibXSLT__parse_stylesheet':
LibXSLT.xs:1089: error: `xmlDocPtr' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1089: error: syntax error before "doc_copy"
LibXSLT.c:1282: error: `xsltStylesheetPtr' undeclared (first use in this functio
n)
LibXSLT.c:1282: error: syntax error before "RETVAL"
LibXSLT.xs:1097: error: `doc' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1097: error: syntax error before "x_PmmSvNodeExt"
LibXSLT.xs:1101: error: `doc_copy' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1108: error: `xmlGenericErrorFunc' undeclared (first use in this func
tion)
LibXSLT.xs:1108: error: syntax error before "LibXSLT_debug_handler"
LibXSLT.xs:1115: error: `RETVAL' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.c: In function `XS_XML__LibXSLT__parse_stylesheet_file':
LibXSLT.c:1339: error: `xsltStylesheetPtr' undeclared (first use in this functio
n)
LibXSLT.c:1339: error: syntax error before "RETVAL"
LibXSLT.xs:1135: error: `xmlGenericErrorFunc' undeclared (first use in this func
tion)
LibXSLT.xs:1135: error: syntax error before "LibXSLT_debug_handler"
LibXSLT.xs:1142: error: `RETVAL' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1142: error: syntax error before "xmlChar"
LibXSLT.xs: In function `XS_XML__LibXSLT_lib_init_callbacks':
LibXSLT.xs:1156: error: `xmlInputMatchCallback' undeclared (first use in this fu
nction)
LibXSLT.xs:1156: error: syntax error before "LibXSLT_input_match"
LibXSLT.c: In function `XS_XML__LibXSLT__Stylesheet_transform':
LibXSLT.c:1444: error: `xsltStylesheetPtr' undeclared (first use in this functio
n)
LibXSLT.c:1444: error: syntax error before "self"
LibXSLT.xs:1188: error: `xmlDocPtr' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1188: error: syntax error before "real_dom"
LibXSLT.xs:1190: error: `xmlNodePtr' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1193: error: `xsltTransformContextPtr' undeclared (first use in this
function)
LibXSLT.xs:1193: error: syntax error before "ctxt"
LibXSLT.xs:1194: error: `xsltSecurityPrefsPtr' undeclared (first use in this fun
ction)
LibXSLT.c:1460: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1199: error: `doc' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1199: error: syntax error before "x_PmmSvNodeExt"
LibXSLT.xs:1219: error: `xmlGenericErrorFunc' undeclared (first use in this func
tion)
LibXSLT.xs:1219: error: syntax error before "LibXSLT_debug_handler"
LibXSLT.xs:1230: error: `ctxt' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1236: error: `sec' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1244: error: `dtd_prev' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1245: error: `dtd_next' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1248: error: `real_dom' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1252: error: syntax error before "cur"
LibXSLT.xs:1253: error: `cur' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1260: error: `XSLT_STATE_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1274: error: `XML_HTML_DOCUMENT_NODE' undeclared (first use in this f
unction)
LibXSLT.xs:1278: error: `xmlChar' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1278: error: syntax error before ')' token
LibXSLT.xs:1283: error: syntax error before "real_dom"
LibXSLT.c: In function `XS_XML__LibXSLT__Stylesheet_transform_file':
LibXSLT.c:1573: error: `xsltStylesheetPtr' undeclared (first use in this functio
n)
LibXSLT.c:1573: error: syntax error before "self"
LibXSLT.xs:1296: error: `xmlDocPtr' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1296: error: syntax error before "real_dom"
LibXSLT.xs:1299: error: `xsltTransformContextPtr' undeclared (first use in this
function)
LibXSLT.xs:1299: error: syntax error before "ctxt"
LibXSLT.xs:1300: error: `xsltSecurityPrefsPtr' undeclared (first use in this fun
ction)
LibXSLT.c:1587: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1317: error: `xmlGenericErrorFunc' undeclared (first use in this func
tion)
LibXSLT.xs:1317: error: syntax error before "LibXSLT_debug_handler"
LibXSLT.xs:1323: error: `source_dom' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1330: error: `ctxt' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1336: error: `sec' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1339: error: `real_dom' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1341: error: `XSLT_STATE_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1358: error: `XML_HTML_DOCUMENT_NODE' undeclared (first use in this f
unction)
LibXSLT.xs:1362: error: syntax error before "xmlChar"
LibXSLT.xs:1364: error: `xmlNodePtr' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1364: error: syntax error before "real_dom"
LibXSLT.c: In function `XS_XML__LibXSLT__Stylesheet_DESTROY':
LibXSLT.c:1675: error: `xsltStylesheetPtr' undeclared (first use in this functio
n)
LibXSLT.c:1675: error: syntax error before "self"
LibXSLT.c:1678: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.c: In function `XS_XML__LibXSLT__Stylesheet__output_string':
LibXSLT.c:1711: error: `xsltStylesheetPtr' undeclared (first use in this functio
n)
LibXSLT.c:1711: error: syntax error before "self"
LibXSLT.xs:1390: error: `xmlOutputBufferPtr' undeclared (first use in this funct
ion)
LibXSLT.xs:1390: error: syntax error before "output"
LibXSLT.xs:1392: error: syntax error before '*' token
LibXSLT.xs:1393: error: `xmlCharEncodingHandlerPtr' undeclared (first use in thi
s function)
LibXSLT.xs:1394: error: `xmlDocPtr' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.c:1724: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1397: error: syntax error before "if"
LibXSLT.xs:1399: error: `encoder' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1400: error: syntax error before "xmlChar"
LibXSLT.xs:1406: error: `xmlGenericErrorFunc' undeclared (first use in this func
tion)
LibXSLT.xs:1406: error: syntax error before "LibXSLT_debug_handler"
LibXSLT.xs:1411: error: `output' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1412: error: `xmlOutputWriteCallback' undeclared (first use in this f
unction)
LibXSLT.xs:1412: error: syntax error before "LibXSLT_iowrite_scalar"
LibXSLT.xs:1417: error: `doc' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1422: error: `bytes_vs_chars' undeclared (first use in this function)

LibXSLT.xs:1423: error: syntax error before "xmlChar"
LibXSLT.xs: At top level:
LibXSLT.xs:1426: error: `results' undeclared here (not in a function)
LibXSLT.xs:1426: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
LibXSLT.c:1768: error: syntax error before '(' token
LibXSLT.c:1769: error: syntax error before '(' token
LibXSLT.c:1769: error: syntax error before ')' token
LibXSLT.c:1771: error: syntax error before '(' token
LibXSLT.c: In function `XS_XML__LibXSLT__Stylesheet_output_fh':
LibXSLT.c:1786: error: `xsltStylesheetPtr' undeclared (first use in this functio
n)
LibXSLT.c:1786: error: syntax error before "self"
LibXSLT.xs:1436: error: `xmlOutputBufferPtr' undeclared (first use in this funct
ion)
LibXSLT.xs:1436: error: syntax error before "output"
LibXSLT.xs:1437: error: syntax error before '*' token
LibXSLT.xs:1438: error: `xmlCharEncodingHandlerPtr' undeclared (first use in thi
s function)
LibXSLT.xs:1439: error: `xmlDocPtr' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.c:1797: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1442: error: syntax error before "if"
LibXSLT.xs:1444: error: `encoder' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1445: error: syntax error before "xmlChar"
LibXSLT.xs:1451: error: `xmlGenericErrorFunc' undeclared (first use in this func
tion)
LibXSLT.xs:1451: error: syntax error before "LibXSLT_debug_handler"
LibXSLT.xs:1456: error: `output' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.xs:1457: error: `xmlOutputWriteCallback' undeclared (first use in this f
unction)
LibXSLT.xs:1457: error: syntax error before "LibXSLT_iowrite_fh"
LibXSLT.xs:1462: error: `doc' undeclared (first use in this function)
LibXSLT.c: At top level:
LibXSLT.c:1830: error: syntax error before "void"
LibXSLT.c:1830: error: syntax error before '(' token
LibXSLT.c: In function `XS_XML__LibXSLT__Stylesheet_output_file':
LibXSLT.c:1845: error: `xsltStylesheetPtr' undeclared (first use in this functio
n)
--------------------REMAINING CODE WILL BE IN SECOND POST----------------------
```

I think the errors are related to DLLs that should pre-exist in order to install this package:

```
LibXSLT.c:2056: error: syntax error before "if" 
LibXSLT.c:2059: error: syntax error before '(' token 
dmake.exe: Error code 129, while making 'LibXSLT.o' SHLOMIF/XML-LibXSLT-1.73.tar.gz C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK 
Running make test
Can't test without successful make
Running make install
Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Failed during this command: SHLOMIF/XML-LibXSLT-1.73.tar.gz : make NO
cpan>
```

Comment: Did you install the [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/) library first? The `XML::LibXSLT` module provides a Perl wrapper for that library, but it does not include the library itself.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding ppm availability, you could put in a request to activestate but don't hold your breath
Slightly better chance requesting from `cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/ppm-request.html`
[This](http://win32.perl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Vanilla_Perl_and_GnuWin32#LibXML_install) might work for you. The 3rd option is install `Msys/MinGW` and compile everything yourself like [this](http://ingar.satgnu.net/devenv/mingw32/base.html)

**update:** could also request from sisyphusion.tk , or simply install strawberryperl.com, it comes with libxml/libxslt

Comment: None of this will matter if the `libxslt` library was not already installed first.

Comment: @mob - It seems that windows binaries are already available at ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/. Do you have any idea how can we use it to compile XML::LibXSLT module

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try to add the following repository in the ppm. This has LibXSLT module version 1.6

ppm rep add trouchelle.com http://trouchelle.com/ppm12/

This should work for your perl version. For more information please visit
http://trouchelle.com/perl/ppmrepview.pl

Installing XS module through cpan, on ActivePerl is a little pain.